# How to set maximum message characters limit in ejabberd

Tags: configuration, message, ejabberd

I would like to know how to set maximum limit to message characters in ejabberd. I want my users to send messages limited to 2000 characters.

I've searched a lot but i have not find anything useful to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The closer thing I can think is this ejabberd_c2s listener option, that probably you already noticed:

> max_stanza_size: Size: This option specifies an approximate maximum
>   size in bytes of XML stanzas. Approximate, because it is calculated
>   with the precision of one block of read data. For example
>   {max_stanza_size, 65536}. The default value is infinity. Recommended
>   values are 65536 for c2s connections and 131072 for s2s connections.
>   s2s max stanza size must always much higher than c2s limit. Change
>   this value with extreme care as it can cause unwanted disconnect if
>   set too low.

Comment: Yes, i have seen this configuration. But it does not seem right to limit a stanza size due to a message size problem. However, thanks a lot :D